# can't add itertools.so to the path in os

Tags: macos, python-2.7, python-itertools

I am using the mac os x 10.10.1, and python2.7. Just recently I have installed the blend environment and I tried to create some animation programmatically through a python program called batch2.py together blender.

if I execute the program in `python batch2.py`, it works with no problem, To make the animation, I have to execute it by the command
- `/Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender -b scene.blend -P batch2.py`,

however a error is shown up saying :

```
print ( list(itertools.imap(None, numbers, decimals))  )
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'imap'
```

batch2.py is shown below, a simple python program.

```
import sys    
import itertools

print (sys.path)
print (".....................")

letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
booleans = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
numbers = [23, 20, 44, 32, 7, 12]
decimals = [0.1, 0.7, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5]

print ( list(itertools.imap(None, numbers, decimals))  )
```

since the blender application has its own python environment based python 3.4, so I just add the system os environment to the sys.path as below.

```
sys.path.append("/Users/abc/anaconda/lib/python2.7")
sys.path.append("/Users/abc/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
sys.path.append("/Users/abc/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/")
sys.path.append("/Users/abc/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin")
sys.path.append("/Users/abc/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-mac")
sys.path.append("/Users/abc/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk")
sys.path.append("/Users/abc/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-old")
sys.path.append("/Users/abc/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL")
sys.path.append("/Users/abc/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.2.3-py2.7.egg")
sys.path.append("/Users/abc/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/runipy-0.1.1-py2.7.egg")
sys.path.append("/Users/abc/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-5.8-py2.7.egg")
```

but still it doesn't work.

I found itertools is in the path of '/Users/abc/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/itertools.so', but how could I use it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding Python 2.7 folders to your path won't allow Python 3.X to use 2.7 modules.

You don't really need `imap` here anyway - you can use the built-in `zip` function to combine sequences. Replace

```
print ( list(itertools.imap(None, numbers, decimals))  )
```

With

```
print(list(zip(numbers, decimals)))
```

---

If you really must have `imap` no matter what, you can copy-paste the implementation given in the `itertools` documentation, into your own script. (With a small modification for version compatibility)

```
def imap(function, *iterables):
    # imap(pow, (2,3,10), (5,2,3)) --> 32 9 1000
    iterables = list(map(iter, iterables))
    while True:
        args = [next(it) for it in iterables]
        if function is None:
            yield tuple(args)
        else:
            yield function(*args)
```

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. but still is there any way to use itertools.imap(),because I have a module which needs to use itertools.

Comment: @user824624 No. There is no way to use a Python 2 module in Python 3.

Comment: then is there a way to add itertools module in the blender envioroment

Comment: You could just use the built-in `map`, which in 3.X is more or less equivalent to `imap`. Do note that it no longer accepts `None` as a first argument though. (but again, you can use `zip` in that case)

Comment: @user824624 Basically - your script is being executed in a Python 3 environment, so you need to use python 3 syntax and APIs.  You can still import and use `itertools`, it just doesn't contain `imap` anymore (one of the non-backward-compatible features of python 3).  [Here is its API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html). Note that `map` in Python 3 [works like `itertools.imap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/future_builtins.html#future_builtins.map).  However, In this particular situation, Kevin's suggestion is better.

Comment: Thanks,@JRichardSnape, I know now I have to use itertools.map in blender python3 based environment, however there is no itertools module in blender python3 based environment, how could I import the itertools module into its environment

Comment: There is no `itertools.map` method. `map` is in the built-in module.